# I want add library to Android Studio, but I deal with the error:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3

[this is build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhLvq.png)

Answer (score -1):

You should add the mavenCentral repo in your project level gradle file, like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: Try moving the maven repo in the "allrojects" note, below "buildscript"

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}`